# Laravel how to save data which in forloop

Tags: php, laravel, save

I have data which I  need to save into database. Here's the example
[image: Example input]
Now my controller:

```
public function saveRequest(Request $request){

$count = count($request->input('itemname'));
$purchase = new PrRequest;

    for ($i=0; $i<$count; $i++){
            $data[] = array(
            'pr_no' => $request->input('pr_no')[$i],    
            'pr_date' => $request->input('pr_date')[$i],
            'department' => $request->input('department')[$i],
            'remarks' => $request->input('remarks')[$i],
            'notes' => $request->input('notes')[$i],
            'requested_by' => $request->input('requested_by')[$i],
            'item_id' => $request->input('itemname')[$i],
            'qty' => $request->input('qty')[$i],
            'type' => $request->input('type')[$i],
            'uom' => $request->input('uom'),
            'pd_date' => $request->input('pd_date')[$i]
            );
        $purchase->fill($data[$i])->save(); 
    }
    return Response::json($data, 200, array(), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
}
```

I got error after clicking save button.

```
ErrorException in helpers.php line 671:
preg_replace(): Parameter mismatch, pattern is a string while replacement is an array
```

Any solution? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You don't want to use `foreach`loop?

Comment: I don't have idea how to use foreach in relate to my code. Can you provide an example? @aldrin27

Comment: What is the result of `$request`?

Comment: If I return it to json.. this is the ouput
http://imgur.com/lCSKYX8

Comment: @Kerwin, match the form to your table column names. This way when you submit your form, you can pass them to $model -> fill($request ->all()); you will save a lot of code and a lot of time.

Comment: Already tried that only I'm not using all()  because for the array counter but I will try your idea. Thanks @mdamia

Comment: [Example I use same input name and database column name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wISh4.png) Just if someone come and need other example see link above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are calling fill every iteration, it s better to build data then do a batch insert

```
for ($i=0; $i<$count; $i++){
        $data[] = array(
        'pr_no' => $request->input('pr_no')[$i],    
        'pr_date' => $request->input('pr_date')[$i],
        'department' => $request->input('department')[$i],
        'remarks' => $request->input('remarks')[$i],
        'notes' => $request->input('notes')[$i],
        'requested_by' => $request->input('requested_by')[$i],
        'item_id' => $request->input('itemname')[$i],
        'qty' => $request->input('qty')[$i],
        'type' => $request->input('type')[$i],
        'uom' => $request->input('uom'),
        'pd_date' => $request->input('pd_date')[$i]
        );
    $purchase->fill($data[$i])->save(); <-- remove this
}

DB::table(table name) -> insert($data); <-- this is better, one query.
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much. I never thought on that DB::table(table name)